# What's the best time to sleep after Fajr?

Tags: practical-islam, sunnah

I know it's better to avoid sleeping in the morning, but if I had to sleep(due to late night work), what would be the best time to sleep after Fajr?

Is it after sunrise or after Ishraq? Basically, I want to know if sleeping before Ishraq is forbidden or not?

Please support your answer with authentic references from the Holy Quran or Hadiths.

Comment: I've read the [fatwa link](http://islamqa.com/en/ref/2063/sleep%20fajr) and learned that I have to wait for sun rise after fajr to follow sunnah and then it's permissible(ie, not prohibited) to sleep before Ishraq(to gain strength to do work in rest of the day). If it's correct means,Tarek Eldeeb's answer should get the bounty. Jazakallah.

Comment: it is not forbidden. it is highly recommended to do not sleep between Fajr and sunrise. it has many rewards and benefits including worldly benefits like increase in income. after sunrise you can sleep some to refresh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing forbids it! Here's a [fatwa](http://islamqa.com/en/ref/2063/sleep%20fajr).
Although it's preferred to sit till sunrise and say Morning's Azkar, Quran, .. etc.

> As far as a person’s sleeping after praying Fajr is concerned, no text (of Qur’aan or hadeeth) has been reported to indicate that this is prohibited, so the general principle applies (i.e., everything is permitted except that which has been expressly forbidden).
>
> But the practice of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) and his Companions after praying Fajr was to remain sitting in the place where they had prayed until the sun rose, as is reported in Saheeh Muslim (1/463) in the hadeeth of Sammaak ibn Harb, who said: “I asked Jaabir ibn Samurah, ‘Did you used to sit with the Messenger of Allaah?’ He said, ‘Yes, frequently. He would not get up from the place where he had prayed Subh until the sun rose. When the sun rose, he would get up. They used to talk about things that had happened during the Jaahiliyyah, and they would laugh and smile.’”

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard of anything that forbids sleeping before or after Ishraq, as long as you attend Fajr prayer, there is no restriction on when to sleep.

I am almost certain that the Holy Quraan does not include any verses forbidding anything like this. So, my advice is: since it is allowed to sleep whenever you want, just 'sleep whenever you feel comfortable', and do not research this further since researching it will only lead you to some conflicting personal opinions with no real importance.

P.S. In all my life, I've heard (with no real evidence) references to these two habits:

- It's preferred to have a quick power nap of 15-20 minutes after Midday.
- It is not preferred (markrooh) to sleep between Asr and Maghreb (sunset)

Comment: I've heard it was discouraged to sleep during the whole of Maghrib too, but never heard any evidence for it.

Answer (score 2):

Aslamumun Alaikum.

I reached here for "Mid-day Nap" timings "Qailoolah" but not found my question. We a group of friends and my family share such good information. I read in so many Ahadeeth not to say anything from Rasoole Kareem what you are not sure he said in Ahadeethe-Moudhooh.
So I don't fwd anything without being sure it is correct. search so many ref for it.
One I my friends fwdd " 01. Refrain from sleeping between ***`fajr and Zuhar,`*** Maghrib n Isha "

I read in an Hadeeth (meaning)From a companion. " We delayed our meals and Nap on Jummah for Jummah Prayers ie took after the prayer" 
92 hadith found in 'Food, Meals' of Sahih Bukhari.

[315] Narrated Sahl bin Sad: We used to be happy on Fridays, for there was an old lady who used to pull out the roots of Silq and put it in a cooking pot with some barley. When we had finished the prayer, we would visit her and she would present that dish before us. So we used to be happy on Fridays because of that,

***> and we never used to take our meals or have a mid-day Nap except after

> the Friday prayer.***

By Allah, that meal contained no fat.

(Book #65, Hadith #315)

"Nap before Zuhr Prayer" is the point to confirm.
Jazakumalla

Answer (score 1):

The best time to sleep is is **Midday**.

> Narrated by Sahl bin Sad, "We used to have a midday nap and take our meals after the Jumua (prayer)." (Sahih Bukhari, Volume 8, Book 74, No 296)
>
> Narrated by Thumama, "Anas said, "Um Sulaim used to spread a leather sheet for the Prophet and he used to take a midday nap on that leather sheet at her home."" (Sahih Bukhari, Volume 8, Book 74, No 298)

The Quran doesn't recommend it directly, but suggests that it's normal for people to rest in the middle of the day.

> O you who have believed, let those whom your right hands possess and those who have not [yet] reached puberty among you ask permission of you [before entering] at three times: before the dawn prayer and **when you put aside your clothing [for rest] at noon** and after the night prayer.

I also recall somewhere that the Prophet SAWS did the Hijra to Medina during the midday because that was when everyone was asleep and the time when his enemies were least likely to see him.

Comment: jazakallah, but I need to know,if sleeping before Ishraq is forbidden or not?,pls read the question fully.

Comment: @NAZIK AFAIK, there is nothing prohibiting it, so it should be allowed. Ideally it should be after zuhur prayers, but I will check if I have free time.